# how to clear all files from the git from the "Changed but not updated:" list

Tags: git

I have a list of files in my "Changed but not updated:" list which git has picked up as having changed but there are no changes in the files themselves

I've added all the files that have changes so I simply want to clear the "Changed but not updated:" list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git checkout .` seems to do the trick for me. This is hinted at in the message shown by `git status`, though it usually mentions giving a file as an argument. `checkout` with paths set the contents of the working tree to match the index (which should contain the files you selected with `git add`).

From the man page:

> `git checkout [--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…`
>
> When  or --patch are given, git checkout does not switch branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named  (most often a commit). In this case, the -b and --track options are meaningless and giving either of them results in an error. The  argument can be used to specify a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree) to update the index for the given paths before updating the working tree.

Comment: I think your probably right so I've marked you as the answer but I went with this git ls-files -m | xargs -i git checkout "{}" just so I could be completely sure i was only checking out the files I needed

Answer (score 0):

If you have files in the staging area, you should use :

```
git checkout -- [path to files]
```

If you have committed your changes already, you can do :

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use:

`git add <file>` to add the file into the staged changes,

or

`git checkout -- <file>` to reset it back to what is currently staged.

This is explained in the `git status` message:

```
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

Or if you want to blow away all your changes (including staged changes) use:

`git reset --hard HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick to clean "Changes not staged for commit"

```
git checkout -- .
```